# localdb Create new user and database with powershell

Tags: powershell, localdb

I am writing a powershell to create a new database and a user:

To do this I need to run this:

```
sqlcmd -S (localdb)\MyInstance
```

and then run

```
1> CREATE DATABASE foo;
2> GO
1> USE foo;
2> GO
```

But when I save the script, after sqlcmd-S command it requires me to type the rest of the script.

Is it possible to script the database part?

Comment: There are a ton of cmdlets in this module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.300 Their site is good to at explaining all of them https://dbatools.io/functions/ certainly they'd have what you want done in native powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query=@"
Create database foo
go
use foo
go
"@
Sqlcmd -S <instance> -d master -Q $query
```

This way You have query saved in variable and can use it within  Sqlcmd

Yes, You can do sqlcmd -S  -d master -